# POWER BI datesdifference excluding weekends

Tags: powerbi

This is formula that i use

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Dates[IsWorkDay]),DATESBETWEEN(Dates[Date],
          'table1'[date1],'table1'[Date2])))
```

This is the formula I use... between dates that look like below image.. I want to exclude weekends..... but the result that I get is not correct .... when the actual difference is only one day ... I get it as 4 days ... it differs a lot.. can some one please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX9SK.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Data type of all the dates in the formula needs to be in the same format.

For Example: keep it as just date(mm/dd/yy).

Your calculated column is right and it should work once you fix the data types.